# Adding another link inside a list of links expanded to fill the whole li

Tags: css, html-lists

What I have now is shown [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/965zT/2/): a bunch of floating `li`s that each contains a link expanded to the whole `li` by `display: block`.

Now, what I want to do is add another link inside each `li` (a close button, in my case). Something like in the image below. But I still want the whole rest of the square to be clickable and to follow the original link as it does now.

[image: The same as the jsFiddle output, but with a separate close link.]

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to li elements. Then, give this to your close links:

```
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/965zT/3/